# Is possible to create a JSON RESTful OAuth2 server?

Tags: json, rest, oauth, jwt

The part where user needs to enter their creds can also be shown if the client app redirects to a stateless static page alongwith the some params, that belongs to the oauth-server.com domain so that no other app has access to username and pwd.

After *POST* -ing this form to oauth-server.com, Is there a way to redirect the user back to the client app without the oauth-server redirecting via a browser session? Is there a json restful mechanism to OAUTH2?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question, redirect_uri exists for the sole purpose of letting the client app(web, iOS or android) know status of the authentication request.

And OAuth2 server cannot do anything other than redirecting, because where the server will redirect to? (which is what redirect_uri anyways).

Refer the following articles for best practices to redirect data to installed / mobile client app

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

specifically this section, 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

Hope that helps!

Comment: My question is can a rest json api based auth server be implemented?

Comment: I understand that , it's not possible with authorisation flow , oauth has other flows which work for your criteria,  Resource Owner Credential flow , it will make api request to auth server

Comment: what is  Resource Owner Credential flow? is it in the docs link you gave?

Comment: here it is, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3, but you can always search in google to get variety of articles

Comment: ah you mean the oauth2 flow